# Specify an adapter for multiple xsd types

Tags: java, jaxb

I'm trying to map different formats onto 3 xsd types, xs:dateTime, xs:date, and xs:time. I'm doing a bit of codegen in my project, and do not have a bindings file, though I do have a package-info.

```
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapters({
    @javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapter(value = com.codegen.pojo.lib.adapters.XmlDateTimeFormatter.class, type = com.codegen.pojo.lib.types.IXmlDateTime.class)
})
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchemaTypes({
    @javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchemaType(name = "dateTime", type = com.codegen.pojo.lib.types.XmlDateTime.class),
    @javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchemaType(name = "date", type = com.codegen.pojo.lib.types.XmlDate.class),
    @javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchemaType(name = "time", type = com.codegen.pojo.lib.types.XmlTime.class)
})
@com.codegen.pojo.lib.annotations.XMLDateTimeFormat(format = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXXX")
@com.codegen.pojo.lib.annotations.XMLDateFormat(format = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'")
@com.codegen.pojo.lib.annotations.XMLTimeFormat(format = "'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXXX")
package my_pkg;
```

All 3 of the Xml(Date/Time) classes mentioned in the XmlSchemaType annotations implement the IXmlDateTime interface.
The adapter:

```
public class XmlDateTimeFormatter extends XmlAdapter<String, IXmlDateTime> {

    private final DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormat;
    private final DateTimeFormatter dateFormat;
    private final DateTimeFormatter timeFormat;

    public XmlDateTimeFormatter(String dateTimeFormatPattern, String dateFormatPattern, String timeFormatPattern) {
        dateTimeFormat = dateTimeFormatPattern == null ? null : DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(dateTimeFormatPattern);
        dateFormat = dateFormatPattern == null ? null : DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(dateFormatPattern);
        timeFormat = timeFormatPattern == null ? null : DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(timeFormatPattern);
    }

    @Override
    public String marshal(IXmlDateTime dateTime) throws Exception {

        if (dateTime instanceof XmlDateTime) {
            return dateTimeFormat.format(dateTime.getCalendar().toGregorianCalendar().toZonedDateTime());
        } else if (dateTime instanceof XmlDate) {
            return dateFormat.format(dateTime.getCalendar().toGregorianCalendar().toZonedDateTime());
        } else if (dateTime instanceof XmlTime) {
            return timeFormat.format(dateTime.getCalendar().toGregorianCalendar().toZonedDateTime());
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public IXmlDateTime unmarshal(String dateTime) throws Exception {
        XMLGregorianCalendar calendar = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(dateTime);
        QName xmlFormat = calendar.getXMLSchemaType();

        if (xmlFormat.equals(DatatypeConstants.DATETIME)) {
            return new XmlDateTime(calendar);
        } else if (xmlFormat.equals(DatatypeConstants.DATE)) {
            return new XmlDate(calendar);
        } else if (xmlFormat.equals(DatatypeConstants.TIME)) {
            return new XmlTime(calendar);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

The adapter is added to a Marshaller/Unmarshaller created from a JAXBContext. Unfortunately, neither the marshal or unmarshal get called. Any thoughts on how I could fix this?